# Other way of integrating improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I have an improper integral
$$\int \limits_1^2 \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{2-x}}\frac{1}{(x+2)^3}dx$$
It can be solved using integration of indefinite integral and then applying Fundamental theorem of calculus. But this way is really tedious. Are there other ways for solving it?

Comment: How do you integrate? One way would be to first introduce $t=\sqrt{(x-1)/(2-x)}$, and then introduce $u$ via $t=(\sqrt{3}/2)\tan u$. This will result in a very easy trigonometric integral. But maybe that is what you mean by "using integration of indefinite integral..."? Please clarify.

Comment: @mickep I used your first substitution. It gave me $\int (2t^4 + 2t^2)/(4t^2 + 3)^3 dt$. Then I can integrate it as rational fraction. However, as I sad it is a very long way. As for you second substitution, after applying it doesn't seem to me as a "very easy trigonometric integral".

Comment: For the second one, the integrand I got was $$-\frac{12 \cos (2 u)+\cos (4 u)-13}{384 \sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: @mickep oh, I realised how you did it! Your way is much easier!